# How to type keyboard keys in comments

Tags: support, comments, formatting

In questions/answers we type keyboard keys using `<kbd>KEY</kbd>` which renders <kbd>KEY</kbd>. It does not work in comments. How can one type keyboard keys in comments?

Comment: As said above typing <kbd>KEY</kbd> does not work in comments.

Comment: Formatting options are intentionally limited in comments. In particular, there is no markup for displaying keyboard keys in comments.

Comment: Generally people use `code formatting` to type keyboard keys in comments, because `<kbd>` is not available. Or just no formatting at all, or _italics_ or **bold**. Click `Help` next to the comment box to check which formatting is available for comments and how to use it (the only other thing that works besides the formatting I already mentioned is link formatting).

Answer (score 8):

Comments provide only a limited amount of markdown formatting, including *italic*, **bold**, `code` (via single/double backticks), magic/shorthand links (for sites `[tex.se]` or tag `[tag:tag]` or...), regular links (like `[text](URL)`). This excludes the use of HTML tags (like `<strong>bold</strong>`) and the shorthand image inclusion format `![text](imageURL)` commonly used in posts.

So there's not HTML `<kbd>`...`</kbd>` keyboard tag formatting supported.

Reference: [Markdown help - comment formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: I just tried having a link in my previous comment, on the main site, to no avail. I try again: [here](osti.gov/biblio/5384184).

Comment: @some_other_in_the_crowd: Specify a valid URL with the `https://` prefix.